# Function get_post and return mysqli_real_escape_string - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, web

I'm a beginner at coding (I just have a small experience with Visual Basic and Pascal) and now I'm trying to learn some Web Development using O'Reilly's book "Learning PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, CSS & HTML 5".

The problem is that he is using MySQL instead of MySQLi, so I need to do small changes when I'm following thought the exercises.

In a chapter called "Accessing MySQL databases using PHP" he built a form where the user can add a new book (with title name, author, year, category and ISBN) to the database. My problem is that I have some error than doesn't allow to see in the web page the new book submitted.

I'm not sure, but I think it has to be something with the get_post and mysqli_real escape_string part.

This is the code I've written:

```
<?php //sqltest.php
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_error($db_server));

mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database)
    or die ("Unable to select database: " . mysqli_error($db_server));

//Deleting a record.
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['isbn']))
    {
        $isbn = get_post('isbn');
        $query = "DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn = '$isbn'";

        if (!mysqli_query($db_server,$query))
            echo "DELETE failed: $query<br>" .
            mysqli_error($query) . "<br><br>";
    }

//Add new elements to the database.
if (isset($_POST['author']) && //Isset -> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.
    isset($_POST['title']) &&
    isset($_POST['category']) &&
    isset($_POST['year']) &&
    isset($_POST['isbn']))
    {
     $author = get_post($db_server, 'author');
     $title = get_post($db_server, 'title'); 
     $category = get_post($db_server, 'category'); 
     $year = get_post($db_server, 'year'); 
     $isbn = get_post($db_server, 'isbn'); 
    }

     $query = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES" .
         "('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn')";

    //Displaying the form.
    echo <<<_END
    <form action = "sqltest.php" method="post"> <pre>
        Author <input type="text" name="author" />
        Title <input type="text" name="title" />
        Category <input type="text" name="category" />
        Year <input type="text" name="year" />
        ISBN <input type="text" name="isbn" />
             <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD" />
    </pre></form>
_END;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM classics";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);

    if (!$result) die ("Database acess failed: " . mysqli_query_error($result));

    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo <<<_END
        <pre>
        Author $row[0]
        Title $row[1]
        Category $row[2]
        Year $row[3]
        ISBN $row[4]
        </pre>
        <form action="sqltest.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes">
        <input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="$row[4]">
        <input type="submit" value="DELETE RECORD"></form>
_END;
    }

    function get_post($db_server, $var)
    {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $_POST[$var]);
    }
    mysqli_close($db_server);
?>
```

Just to explain my problem better: I fill the form with the details from the new book and then I submitted it but the new book doesn't appear on the web page (like the ones added before using MySQL command line).

Thanks for your time,
David

Comment: **Facts:** That book is old, as is the technology described in it (it's actually removed from PHP already). Database interaction has taken big steps in PHP with bind parameters, and you shouldn't need to escape values like that at all. It's better to get a more recent book or other source to learn about this subject, because otherwise you'll end up using the new tech the old way. **Opinion:** `mysqli` seems to be written as an intermediate library to gradually upgrade from old style to bind parameters, but for new development `PDO` is the better choice.

Comment: The actual problem is probably due to the fact that you assign the insert statement's text to `$query`. A couple of lines down, you do actually call `mysqli_query` to execute the select statement, but the insert statement never gets executed.

Comment: @GolezTrol I'm going to follow your advise and I'm going to beginn my "web development journey" somewhere else (leaving that O'Reilly's book behind). To tell the truth, September I'll beginn my bachelor degree in either Computer Enginnering or Computer Sciences, but I wanted to be able to "master" web development as soon as possible to start to work at small projects. Thanks for your answer and your time. :)

Comment: You're welcome. :-) Good for you for wanting to be ahead. It certainly helps if you have a little basic knowledge when you start school or a course. Good luck getting your degree!

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code, specific the name of database columns.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO classics (author, title, category, year, isbn) VALUES ('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn');";
```